# Android Gridview is not refreshed while pressing back button

Tags: android, gridview, back-button

I have one grid view in one activity.I have set Adapter using array-list.
Gridview is displaying the list of the items stored in the database.Let say it is some products.
When i click on any product in the grid-view it will navigate me to product detail screen.
From product detail screen i can delete product.If i delete product and press back button it will navigate me to product list screen.

**Expected:** Product list screen will come without deleted item.

**Actual:**  Product list screen is coming with deleted item. When touch this item it will do nothing.

**Supporting my question,please see below picture**

[image: Supporting my question,please see below p]

Comment: You need to remove the item from the `ArrayList` that you are passing to the `GridView` and call `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: Atcually the items which are passed in the grid-view are fresh but some how UI is not changed.I have done notifyDataSetChanged on adapter but it wan't worked.

Comment: I am re-initializing the whole UI from onResume,is it something that may cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have get gridview items from db in OnResume method of activity. And when u delete any item  and then back press, it will call OnResume method of previous activity where u get new list, and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the grid, in order to recreate the view

Comment: Yes i am doing from onResume

Comment: Then their must be issue in deleting that item from database, otherwise u will not be getting in gridview after it got deleted

Comment: If it is really a problem with delete than it should not come when i re open the same screen from navigation.

Comment: I am re-initializing the whole UI from onResume,is it something that may cause of this problem?

Comment: it's working on fragment also as i update data source in adapter and call notifydatasetchanged and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Try Some like:

```
if (homeGridViewDatas.size() > 0) {
        homeGridViewAdapter = new HomeGridViewAdapter(activity, context,
                homeGridViewDatas);
        gvHome.setAdapter(homeGridViewAdapter);
        homeGridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: I have done notifyDataSetChanged on adapter but it wan't worked.

Comment: I am sorry but i couldn't post the code,other wise i will not prepare the picture.

Comment: I am re-initializing the whole UI from onResume,is it something that may cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should notify the gridadapter which something is changed by calling`notifyDataSetChanged` on it. In `onResume`should be ok. Or when you update it too.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged  is not available for Gridview

Comment: Not GridView, GridAdapter. (The adapter)

Comment: I have done notifyDataSetChanged on adapter but it wan't worked.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you check if the .size of the ArrayList is changed after a delete?

Comment: Yes size is changed i have checked using Log and breakpoints.

Comment: Ok try it: delete an item, back to home screen and reopen your application (don't close it) and check if it's updated in the list

Comment: Still deleted item is coming.

Comment: I am re-initializing the whole UI from onResume,is it something that may cause of this problem?

Comment: if you create a new copy of the UI every time it means the problem is that in the arraylist is never deleted... You get data from a database? Maybe the problem is elsewhere

Comment: what if, i clear the array-list before i filled it?I have done this also.Is is some thing that system maintain cache for performance.

Answer (score 0):

> When i click on any product in the grid-view it will navigate me to
>   product detail screen.

When you go from `gridView` activity (product list screen) to detail activity(product detail screen.), the detail activity is launched on top of your `gridView` activity in Stack.

> If i delete product and press back button it will navigate me to
>   product list screen.

And when you delete a particular product in detail screen and press back button, the detail activity is removed from the stack and hence the gridview activity which was below detail activity comes to foreground and becomes visible.

> Product list screen is coming with deleted item. When touch this item
>   it will do nothing.

However your `gridView` activity still has the previous data.Hence it displays that old data and nothing happens on touch as actual data is different than the one in adapter.

**Solution :**

You need to notify the adapter for gridView in that activity, that the data has been changed and the view must be updated accordingly.

As `onResume()` is called everytime activity comes to foreground and is visible, it is the better place to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `gridadapter`.

Comment: I am re-initializing the whole UI from onResume,is it something that may cause of this problem?